# Deleted file is still showing in my app after clearing storage also

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am extracting audio files and showing in the recyclerview.
I have given delete option after pressing delete button the file is removed from the list and from the file manager but when I reopen the app the audio file appears again at the same place in recycler view but it doesn't play.

But when I recheck the file manager the file is not there and then I cleared the cache and storage but file is still there.
So I reinstall the app but that file is still there but you cannot play it.

And if you delete the file directly from file manager the file doesn't appear in the app instantly.

```
val uri = Uri.parse(getSongsList?.get(item.groupId)?.songData)

          val fdelete = File(uri.path)
          if (fdelete.exists()) {
              Log.e("v", "fscsg")

              if (fdelete.delete()) {
                  Log.e("vdv", "fg")
                  System.out.println("file Deleted :${uri.path}")
              } else {
                  Log.e("vd", "fgcs")

                  System.out.println("file not Deleted :${uri.path}")
              }
          }
          Log.i("ld", getSongsList?.get(0)?.songTitle + " " + item.groupId)

          getSongsList?.removeAt(item.groupId)
          _mainScreenAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

So how it could be possible that when file is not there in the storage still it is appearing in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File file = new File(uriOfFile);
boolean deleted = file.delete();

//delete file from Media Database
scanaddedFile(file);

private void scanaddedFile(String path) {
try {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { path },
            null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    context.getContentResolver()
                            .delete(uri, null, null);
                }
            });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer it was very frustrating. 
There is a media database which hold all the information regarding the media file so when I delete the file it is deleted but still have record in media database and content resolver takes the data from media database hence it is there in the app.
So if we restart the phone then the deleted file is gone from the list so every time we have to delete the file we have to delete it from database record also.

Still looking for how to delete from media database.